# Google App Script Надстройка с пользовательской функцией

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet, google-cloud, deploy, addons

Уважаемые форумчане! Может ли кто-нибудь сказать как реализовать задачу совместного использования  пользовательской функции для Google spreadsheet через создание надстройки. Необходимо чтобы пользователи, установившие надстройку могли использовать содержащую ее функцию

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Суть вопроса совершенно непонятна. Если вы публикуете дополнение, то формула начинает работать не только для каждого установившего, но и для любого, кто открыл Таблицу с формулой, где она была прописана. Пример такого приложения https://numbertext.contributor.pw

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прошу прощения за неточную формулировку вопроса. Имелось ввиду что скрип надстройки (пользовательская функция) не связан с контейнером, т.е. с таблицей, а является автономным. Т.е., чтобы пользователь, открывший произвольную таблицу и установивший надстройку, мог бы применять пользовательскую функцию в своей таблице.

Comment: Пользователь устанавливает надстройку для всех своих Таблиц, иначе она работает для Таблиц, в которых другие пользователи использовали это расширение. Это не всегда может работать, поэтому чаще приходится все же устанавливать дополнение. Скрипт надстройки никак не связан с контейнером, т.к. вам все равно придется регистрировать отдельный проект для этого.

Comment: В проекте App Script помимо пользовательcкой функции у меня есть триггер onOpen() в котором создается меню. При тестовом развертывании (тип дополнение для редактора) менюшка отображается, а попытка применения функции вызывает ошибку "неизвестная функция: имя функции". Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Нужно делать инъекцию. Т.е. создавать меню из того проекта, где лежит функция.